# Logic error with std::replace

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, stl

today I've encountered a logic error while working on a school project. For this project, switching `chars` around is required.

Say for example, the user enters the letter `A`. it is switched to `U`, and all is well. However, the issue occurs when the user enters the letter `U`. The character remains untouched. I've implemented two rules to switch from `A` to `U` and `U` to `A`. The string passes through both of the rules, and therefore is unchanged. How can I prevent this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 string seq;
 getline(cin, seq);

 transform ( seq.begin(), seq.end(), seq.begin(), ::toupper );

 replace ( seq.begin(), seq.end(), 'A', 'U' );
 replace ( seq.begin(), seq.end(), 'U', 'A' );

 cout << seq;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: The string is not unchanged. Consider a string like "U" [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TMW5TdfIfKui0mgw)

Comment: Why `<algorithm.h>` and not `<algorithm>`?

Comment: neither efficient nor nice: you could replace first `A` with a character x that otherwise does not appear in the string then `U` with a second charater y and then replace x with U and y with A respectively

Comment: Works with `<algorithm>` https://ideone.com/ia9fJe

Comment: @user463035818 You can replace `A` with `x`, then `U` with `A`. There is no need for `y`, which would be inefficient as well.

Comment: @DanielLangr hum yes, anyhow even using only a `x` isnt nice

Comment: @JohnnyMopp running the program and inputting the character A simply returns A once more.

Comment: Are you asking how to transform all 'A' to 'U' and all 'U' to 'A' without undoing any previous transformation? I think the answer lies in your usage of `transform`. Think about how you can modify this.

Comment: @Koi Isn't that what you want? I guess I misunderstood the issue. Oh, I see you want to _swap_ A ⟷ U.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Indeed. If A is inputted, return U. If U is inputted, return A.

Comment: As a further hint to that of AndyG, consider how you can make a *single pass* over the string, and use `if`/`else` to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is the case when a range-based for loop is better suitable and more efficient than using a standard algorithm as for example std::transform.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "AUAUA" );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    for ( char &c : s )
    {
        if ( c == 'A' ) c = 'U';
        else if ( c == 'U' ) c = 'A';
    }

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
AUAUA
UAUAU
```

You can write a separate function as for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string & convert( std::string &s1, const std::string &s2, const std::string &s3 )
{
    for ( char &c : s1 )
    {
        auto i = s2.find( c );
        if ( i != std::string::npos ) c = s3[i]; 
    }

    return s1;
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "AUAUA" );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    std::cout << convert( s, "AU", "UA" ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If the string s2 is sorted then you can use the binary search algorithm instead of the linear search.

If you want to use a standard algorithm then in my opinion the most suitable algorithm is `std::for_each` that correcponds to the range-based for loop. For example the first demonstrative program can be rewritten using the algorithm the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "AUAUA" );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    std::for_each( s.begin(), s.end(), 
        []( char &c ) 
        { 
            if ( c == 'A' ) c = 'U';
            else if ( c == 'U' ) c = 'A';
        } );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code worked the way I wanted it to. Thank you very much!

Comment: "more efficient than using a standard algorithm as for example std::transform" [citation needed] ;)

Comment: @YSC Redundant assignments are absent.

Answer (score 10):

With your implementation, you replace `A` to `U` then `U` *back to* `A`:

```
replace ( seq.begin(), seq.end(), 'A', 'U' );
replace ( seq.begin(), seq.end(), 'U', 'A' );
```

You need to make your replacements in one pass, for instance with `std::transform`:

```
std::transform(begin(seq), end(seq), begin(seq), some_function_object);
```

You just have to write this mysterious `some_function_object`. It can be a free-function:

```
char some_function_object(char input) { /* ... */ }
std::transform(begin(seq), end(seq), begin(seq), some_function_object);
```

or a lambda function:

```
std::transform(begin(seq), end(seq), begin(seq), [](char input) { /* ... */ } );
```

This function object must take a `char` and return:

- `A` if `input` is `U`;
- `U` if `input` is `A`;
- `input` otherwise.

And how should you call it if its a free function? Well, why not a self-descriptive name like `swapAandU`?